# Query Multiple OR conditions in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large table with dozens of similar column headers, all of which contain different characters. I need to query all these columns conditionally based on whether they contain certain characters. For example, let's say I have the following table named ElementResults:

| H_Status | He_Status | Li_Status | Be_Status | B_Status | C_Status | N_Status | O_Status | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U | U | I | U | U | E | U | U | Random Datetime1 |
| U | U | U | R | U | U | U | U | Random Datetime2 |
| E | U | U | U | U | U | U | U | Random Datetime3 |
| U | I | U | U | U | I | R | U | Random Datetime4 |
| U | U | U | U | E | U | U | I | Random Datetime5 |
| U | U | I | U | U | U | U | U | Random Datetime6 |
| I | E | U | U | U | U | U | E | Random Datetime7 |
| U | U | U | U | I | U | U | E | Random Datetime8 |
| R | U | U | U | U | U | U | E | Random Datetime9 |

I need to query all of these "..._Status" columns based on whether or not they have either an 'E',  OR an 'I', OR an 'R' char.

I'd like to avoid an extremely wordy, lengthy, and unreadable query by combining headers and desirable chars into my query, but I haven't been successful. I tried grouping chars at least by trying to search individual columns like

```
SELECT * FROM ElementResults
WHERE H_Status LIKE ('I', 'R', 'E')
```

but that was giving me an `incorrect syntax near ','` error. Any suggestions?

Comment: `H_Status IN ('I', 'R', 'E')`?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Should each column has one of those values or at least one?

Answer (score 0):

change `like` to `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM ElementResults
WHERE H_Status in ('I', 'R', 'E')
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=624d2e363660caf098aa1f27399600fb)

| H_Status | He_Status | Li_Status | Be_Status | B_Status | C_Status | N_Status | O_Status | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | U | U | U | U | U | U | U | Random Datetime3 |
| I | E | U | U | U | U | U | E | Random Datetime7 |
| R | U | U | U | U | U | U | E | Random Datetime9 |